# How do I make adjectives from names of regions? California → Californian. Easy. Zabaykalsky Krai →?

Tags: word-request, word-formation

Is there some universal rule? Do I even need to add any suffixes? Maybe, I can use those proper nouns on their own, as modifiers, can't I? I see three options: 'Zabaikalian voters' (or 'Zabaykalskian'?), 'Zabaykaksky Krai voters', 'Zabaykalsky voters'. Which one is correct? If none, how do I say that then?

Comment: Why not *"voters in Zabaykaksky Krai"?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no rule. They are not simply **made**. No, you don't need suffixes.

Some cities and regions have adjectival forms: others don't. Paris, for example, has Parisian but London has no equivalent. And using adjectival forms can be misleading. A man may be Cornish (from the S.W.English county of Cornwall) but not a 'Cornish voter' if he now lives in London.

As [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_adjectivals_and_demonyms_for_cities) points out (and it's also true of regions),

> A common practice is to use a city's name as if it were an adjective.

'London voters', 'London's voters' and 'voters in London' are all commonly used. If the place is always referred to as Zabaykalsky Krai (like New York *State*) then do not drop the 'Krai'. So 'Zabaykalsky Krai voters', 'Zabaykalsky Krai's voters' or (as AIQ says) '*voters in* Zabaykalsky Krai' would all be correct.

Comment: You mean: simply not made. :)

Comment: @Lambie :) Hmm. 'That sort of thing is not simply done.' 'That sort of thing is simply not done.' Hmmmm.

Comment: My dear Old Brixtonian: They are not simply made. [means: They are difficult to make//They are simply not made. [they aren't on, one does not do them]. Didn't you mean the former rather than the latter? I would say that they simply aren't done. One just does  not try and make them.

Comment: So you drop the 'Krai' part, right?

Comment: Perhaps I mislead you into thinking I knew something about Russian place-names, which I'm afraid I don't, though I have now found out that a krai is similar to an oblast: a word I *did* know! I will edit the last part of my answer.

Comment: @Lambie, my old fussbudget! Replying to 'How do I make...' I said, 'They are not simply MADE', emboldening the word 'made'. Enough, surely, to discourage the questioner from making up his own adjective. Although I am much given to using the word 'one', I think it best avoided when trying to help an English language learner. One simply doesn't use it here.